# XSL transformation - how to set attribute value to element value

Tags: html, xslt

hy, i have this HTML

```
<mods>
<name type="personal" ID="">
<role>
<roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Author</roleTerm>
</role>
<identifier type="type1" value="value1">dummy</identifier>
<identifier type="type2" value="value1">dummy</identifier>
<namePart type="given"/>
<namePart type="family"/>
</name>
```

and i would like to transform it to

```
<mods>
<name type="personal" ID="">
<role>
<roleTerm authority="marcrelator" type="text">Author</roleTerm>
</role>
<identifier type="type1">value1</identifier>
<identifier type="type2">value2</identifier>
<namePart type="given"/>
<namePart type="family"/>
</name>
```

the element **identifier** changes its value to the value of the attribute **value**, and then the attribute **value** is deleted.

but the problem is i can figure out how to make a loop to do it to all the elements, i change the first element value (dummy) to its attribute value (value1), and the second one gets the first elements value (value1) also, instead of its value (value2)

the code that does so is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->

    <!--identity template copies everything forward by default-->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/mods/name/identifier/text()">
    <xsl:value-of><xsl:value-of select="/mods/name/identifier/@value" /></xsl:value-of>       
    </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@value"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i also tried creating a loop to go thru all the **identifier** elements, create a new element and set its node value to the attribute value, but i cant figure out the right syntax

```
<xsl:template match="/mods/name/identifier">
<xsl:for-each select="node()">
        <xsl:element name="identifier"><xsl:value-of select="/@value" /></xsl:element>       
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i also tried creating a loop to go thru all the identifier elements,
>   create a new element and set its node value to the attribute value,
>   but i cant figure out the right syntax

How about simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="identifier">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@type"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

There's no need for a "loop": the second template matches `identifier` and will be applied in turn to all matched elements.

Note also that once you are in the context of the matched element, you want to use *relative* paths to the child nodes. Otherwise you will always be selecting the *first* referenced node (in document order, starting from the root).

Answer (score 0):

try this out xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <!--empty template suppresses this attribute-->

  <!--identity template copies everything forward by default-->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/mods/name/identifier">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
      <xsl:for-each select="@*">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="name()='type'">
            <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:attribute>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I haven't seperated the attribute logic in seperate template